# How to convert unformatted time to a python time object

Tags: python, datetime, time

I need to convert all of these to python time objects using or strptime or any such method -

> "8 seconds ago"
>
> "5 minutes ago"
>
> "11 hours ago"
>
> "11:34 AM yesterday"

Comment: do you have a definite format? (also, it would be easier if you could just get the source of the date, rather than parsing a formatted string)

Comment: no these are the examples and some that can be directly converted by strptime (05:18 PM 24/06/15). Actually I can't have the source because I am scrapping this from a website

Comment: so you are looking for a solution that can parse about anything that vaguely hints at a date? like `last friday`, `a week from now`, or even `that day when we went to the beach?`

Comment: This is a somewhat complicated problem and unless some happened to have solved it recently and has the code ready to copy/paste you are going to need to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is there any generalized method other than hardcoding these 4 cases

Comment: so you have a defined format (or a finite list of defined formats)?

Comment: yeah these four. Tell me if there is something other than hardcoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [`parsedatetime` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/) that should parse human-readable date/time text works in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime as pdt # $ pip install parsedatetime

cal = pdt.Calendar()
print(datetime.now())
for time_str in ["8 seconds ago", "5 minutes ago", "11 hours ago",
                 "11:34 AM yesterday"]:
    dt, flags = cal.parseDT(time_str)
    assert flags
    print(dt)
```

#### Output

```
2015-06-26 21:07:19.108521
2015-06-26 21:07:11
2015-06-26 21:02:19
2015-06-26 10:07:19
2015-06-25 11:34:00
```